# new to sphinx - text analysis and search results 'relativity'

Tags: sphinx

being new to sphinx please excuse any mistakes or misused terms.

Sphinx is being used in a web based app with a database of millions of records in order to provide full-text search functionality.

For English content stored in the database the search results are 'accurate' and relative to the search keywords. The same thing does not happen with non-latin characters. I had a look at the morphology configuration setting but the Greek language is not available as an option. Thus for Greek keywords the search results are not always AS relevant to the search keywords as the keywords in English.

Does sphinx perform the same text analysis and indexing to the Greek content the way it does for the English content?

Any information (links, comments, answers) would be helpful.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely affected by the charset_type and charset_table config uptions.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-charset-type

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-charset-table

Out of the box sphinx is only really setup for English and Russian (the languages the primary Sphinx developer happens to speak :)

So you will need to enable utf8 mode, and add the required Greek chars to the charset_table.

The sphinx wiki
http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=charset_tables
has a set of greek config options can copy/paste.